# Metodo PUT nao funciona como os demais em ANGULAR

Tags: javascript, angular, api, crud

Criei uma aplicação crud onde a leitura, leitura por id, criação e deleção funciona numa boa.
O metodo PUT nao funciona, retorna erro de CORS
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ja fiz varios console.log pra ver se o objeto esta sendo passado de forma correta para a função update e está vindo da forma correta (a alteração feita).
Porém, ele nao atualiza o registro.

O codigo das requisições segue abaixo

```js
create(colaborador: Colaborador): Observable<Colaborador> {
    return this.http.post<Colaborador>(environment.apiUrl, colaborador).pipe(map((obj) => obj), catchError(e => this.errorHandler(e)))
  }
  read(): Observable<Colaborador[]> {
    return this.http.get<Colaborador[]>(environment.apiUrl)
  }
  readById(_id: string | null): Observable<Colaborador> {
    const url = `${environment.apiUrl}/${_id}`
    return this.http.get<Colaborador>(url).pipe(map((obj) => obj), catchError(e => this.errorHandler(e)))
  }
  update(colaborador: Colaborador): Observable<Colaborador>{
    const url = `${environment.apiUrl}/${colaborador._id}`
    console.log(colaborador._id)
    console.log(colaborador);
    return this.http.put<Colaborador>(url, colaborador).pipe(retry(2), catchError(e => this.errorHandler(e)))
  }
  delete(_id:number): Observable<Colaborador>{
    const url = `${environment.apiUrl}/${_id}`
    return this.http.delete<Colaborador>(url).pipe(map((obj) => obj), catchError(e => this.errorHandler(e)))
  }
```

Estou usando a API de testes crudcrud.
Já tentei com pipe(map  conforme os outros metodos, porém mesmo resultado. Seria necessário enviar junto alguma opção header?

Comment: Isso é erro de CORS, teria que habilitar a origem de quem está tentando fazer o post, isso faz no back-end!

Comment: Entao. Mas esse back não tenho acesso  e na documentação ele aceita put. E os demais métodos funcionam de boa

Comment: Provavelmente está faltando algum item no seu header que é necessário para você fazer o put. Verifique a documentação da API.